# Github workflow failing when trying to deploy my angular app to ec2 instance

Tags: github, github-actions

I am new to Github workflow and want to deploy my angular app to my ec2 instance using it:

I have the following:

```
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Build application
        run: npm run build --configuration test-website-angular
      - name: Archive build artifacts
        run: tar -zcvf build.tar.gz dist/

  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Transfer build artifacts to EC2 instance
        uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ec2-user
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          source: build.tar.gz
          target: /var/www/html/
      - name: Extract and clean up build artifacts
        run: ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ec2-user@test.com 'tar -zxvf /var/www/angular/build.tar.gz -C /var/www/angular/ && rm /var/www/angular/build.tar.gz'
```

it build fine but on the deploy step I get the error of:

```
tar all files into /tmp/3998473294/TeBaBukwyd.tar
tar: empty archive
exit status 1
```

I am not sure how to solve this and wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction please

Thanks

Comment: did my reply help you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [share artifacts between jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts). They may run on different machines and what is even more important if you use GitHub-hosted agents they are cleaned after a run.

So you need to publish an artifact in your `build` and then download artifact in `deploy` job.

Try something like this:

```yaml
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Build application
        run: npm run build --configuration test-website-angular
      - name: Archive build artifacts
        run: tar -zcvf build.tar.gz dist/
      - name: Upload artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: package
          path: build.tar.gz

  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Download package
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: package
      - name: Display files in working directory
        run: ls
      - name: Transfer build artifacts to EC2 instance
        uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ec2-user
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          source: build.tar.gz
          target: /var/www/html/
      - name: Extract and clean up build artifacts
        run: ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ec2-user@test.com 'tar -zxvf /var/www/angular/build.tar.gz -C /var/www/angular/ && rm /var/www/angular/build.tar.gz'
```